# Не получается создать функцию в rails для получения get -запроса

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Все доброго дня. Я создал api на rails и появилась проблема с функцией get-запроса. Она у меня работает c sqlite3, но с postgreSQL не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
 def index
        categories = Category.left_outer_joins(:todos)
                            .select('categories.id, categories.title, category_id AS todos')
                            .group('categories.id, categories.title')
        render json: categories, status: :ok
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`category_id` входит в выходной набор, но не входит в выражение группировки, и не обрамлено агрегатной функцией.  Это синтаксическая ошибка. Расширение SQLite позволяет выполнить такие запросы, возвращая для этого поля случайно выбранное значение из всех значений группы, а PostgreSQL такого не дозволяет.

Либо уберите это поле из списка вывода, либо обрамите его агрегатной функцией (например, `MAX()`).

Comment: Спасибо. Очень помогли. Я эту строку поправил:.group('categories.id, categories.title,category_id')